# R: Match two columns in different data frames, output multiples

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to match corresponding values of two columns in two different data frames. For every subc-year `pat.id`-wise pair (e.g. 14X-1991) in `df1`, I'd like to search `df2` to create a list/vector/etc with all the `df2$pat.id` of matching combinations (for the example above, US18 and US20).

As a sample:

df1:

```
pat.id subc year
US1    14X  1991
US3    15R  1992
US5    10R  1990
```

df2:

```
pat.id subc year
US18   14X  1991
US20   14X  1991
US33   15R  1992
US34   15R  1992
US37   15R  1992
US50   10R  1990
```

Data:

`df1 <- data.frame(cbind(c("US1", "US3", "US5"), c("14X", "15R", "10R"), c("1991", "1992", "1990")))
colnames(df1) <- c("pat.id", "subc", "year")
df2 <- data.frame(cbind(c("US18", "US20", "US33", "US34", "US37", "US50"), c("14X", "14X", "15R", "15R", "15R", "10R"), c("1991", "1991", "1992", "1992", "1992", "1990")))
colnames(df2) <- c("pat.id", "subc", "year")`

Plugging in concrete values, it has worked for me with 
`df2$pat.id[which(df2$year==1991 & df2$subc=="14X")]`. Now, I'd like to loop through all rows in `df1`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a `merge` operation as far as I can tell:

```
vars <- c("subc","year")
merge(df1[vars], df2[c(vars,"pat.id")], by=vars)

#  subc year pat.id
#1  10R 1990   US50
#2  14X 1991   US18
#3  14X 1991   US20
#4  15R 1992   US33
#5  15R 1992   US34
#6  15R 1992   US37
```

If you only want to pick one row, `sample` randomly from `df2` before merging:

```
merge(
 df1[vars],
 aggregate(pat.id ~ ., data=df2[c("pat.id",vars)], FUN=sample, 1), by=vars
)
#  subc year pat.id
#1  14X 1991   US20
#2  15R 1992   US33
#3  10R 1990   US50
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes the first step easier! Now, I'd like to randomly select ( sample() ) one of the output's `pat.id`s with the same `subc`-`year` combination (e.g. one of US33, US34, US37) and assign/append it to each row of `df1` again. That's where I'm stuck again..

Comment: Thank you again. It works on the sample, but trying it for a similar but only much larger dataframe with the same structure yields: 

[1] subc year     pat.id  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)  -- have you encountered this before?

Comment: @user5835099 - where does it fail - does the `aggregate` work or the `merge` fail ?

Comment: Both seem to run successfully with no errors (and surprisingly quick since it's got 100thousands of rows).  When calling the resulting object, it states "[1] subc year pat.id <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)"